# Using clusrank by group

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr

simple question, I want to perform the one-sample rank test with cluster in data, after searching for a while, I got `clusWilcox.test` from the package `clusrank`. A toy example for illustration:

```
 df = data.frame(x_1 = rnorm(200),
              x_2 = rnorm(200),
              group = c(rep('A',100),rep('B',100)),
              clus = c(rep('a_1',50),rep('a_2',50),rep('b_1',50),rep('b_2',50)))
```

Worked like a charm when used directly

```
clusWilcox.test(x_1,paired = TRUE,cluster = "clus",data = df)
```

But went wrong when I tried to perform the test by group:

```
  temp_test <-
    df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%

    summarise_each(funs(clusWilcox.test(.,paired = TRUE,cluster = "clus")$p.value), vars = c('x_1','x_2')) 

Error in complete.cases(x, cluster, group, stratum) : 
  not all arguments have the same length
```

Seems like a data problem, so I fill the `data` option of the function with `df`, it worked, but test all the data instead of by `group`.

```
      temp_test <-
        df %>%
        group_by(group) %>%

        summarise_each(funs(clusWilcox.test(.,paired = TRUE,cluster = "clus",data = df)$p.value), vars = c('x_1','x_2'))

> temp_test
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  group vars1 vars2
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     0.168 0.136
2 B     0.168 0.136
```

This won't happen when I tried to perform the one-sample `t.test`

```
  temp_test <-
    df %>%
    group_by(group) %>%

    summarise_each(funs(t.test(.)$p.value), vars = c('x_1','x_2'))
```

My guess is that the `clusWilcox.test` somehow could not inherit data from `dplyr`, anyone know how to get the problem fixed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to `?clusWilcox.test`, the `cluster` parameter should be a numeric vector. In your df, it is a factor.

Therefore, running the test separately for group A with your factor `cluster` variable

```
clusWilcox.test(x_1, paired = TRUE, cluster = clus, data = df[df$group == "A", ])
```

results in:

```
    Clustered Wilcoxon signed rank test using Rosner-Glynn-Lee method

data:  x_1; cluster: clus; (from [)x_1; cluster: clus; (from temp)x_1; cluster: clus; (from temp$group == "A")x_1; cluster: clus; (from )
number of observations: 100;  number of clusters: 4
Z = NA, p-value = NA
alternative hypothesis: true shift in location is not equal to 0
```

If you create a new `cluster` variable that is numeric, it runs the tests correctly:

```
 df %>%
 mutate(clus = group_indices(., group, clus)) %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 summarise(pvalue = clusWilcox.test(x_1, paired = TRUE, cluster = clus)$p.value)

  group pvalue
  <fct>  <dbl>
1 A      0.175
2 B      0.801
```

If you want to calculate it for different columns:

```
df %>%
 mutate(clus = group_indices(., group, clus)) %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(x_1, x_2), ~ clusWilcox.test(., paired = TRUE, cluster = clus)$p.value)

  group   x_1   x_2
  <fct> <dbl> <dbl>
1 A     0.264 0.712
2 B     0.794 0.289
```

To indicate that it contains the p-value:

```
df %>%
 mutate(clus = group_indices(., group, clus)) %>%
 group_by(group) %>%
 summarise_at(vars(x_1, x_2), list(pvalue = ~ clusWilcox.test(., paired = TRUE, cluster = clus)$p.value))

  group x_1_pvalue x_2_pvalue
  <fct>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 A          0.264      0.712
2 B          0.794      0.289
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tested it and it works, but with only one column each time, when I change the last line of yours to  `summarise_each(funs(clusWilcox.test(.,paired = TRUE,cluster = "clus",data = df)$p.value), vars = c('x_1','x_2'))`, same problem again, any idea?

Comment: Thank you so much, this is interesting, I need to have a careful read of the manuals.

Comment: Take a look at `?select_helpers`. Also, if you consider this post as helpful, then please accept it :)